# React not re-rendering after state change

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { postComment } from "../../../actions/comments"
import './styles.scss'

export class Comments extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            comment: "",
            author: null
        }
    }

    static propTypes = {
        postComment: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        axios
        .get(`/api/auth/user`)
        .then(res => {
            const author = res.data.id
            this.setState({author});
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const variables = {
            content: this.state.comment,
            post: this.props.post.id,
            author: this.state.author
        }
        this.props.postComment(variables)
        this.setState({content: ""});
    }

    onFieldChange(fieldName) {
        return function (event) {
            this.setState({[fieldName]: event.target.value});
        }
    }

    render() {
            return (
            <Fragment>
                   <div class="input">
                    <form style={{ display:'flex'}} onSubmit={e => this.onSubmit(e)}>
                         <div class="input-group">
                            <input 
                                class="form-control rounded-corner"
                                style={{width: '100%', borderRadius: '5px'}} 
                                onChange={this.onFieldChange('comment').bind(this)}
                                value = {this.state.comment}
                                placeholder="Leave a comments"
                            />
                            <span class="input-group-btn p-l-10">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary f-s-12 rounded-corner">Comment</button>
                            </span>
                         </div>
                      </form>
                </div>
                <div>

                    {/* Comment Lists */}...

                    ))}
                </div>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(
    null,
    { postComment }
)(Comments);
```

This is a page when I add comments to the posts, which works fine but it doesn't update immediately and I have to refresh. The componentDidMount method uses axios to get current user for setting the author for the current comment. I'm changing the state after the form submit, I can't see what the issue is.

Comment: Initially, your state has `comment` and `author` keys but in the submit function you are setting the value of `content` to an empty string shouldn't that be `comment`?

Comment: I don't see any code in your question that displays comments so maybe post code that doesn't work instead of posting the code that adds the comment (according to you this code works). My guess is that you need to refresh the post data after you add a comment.